# Dense data set of locations for flow analysis

Tags: data, tracklog

I want to do some analysis on real world data related to crowd flows and now I am looking for a publicly available (or at least available to academia) data set of trackings in a crowd. The data set does not neccesarilly have to be from humans, eg. locations of kettle's would also work. The required features are:

- Dense in the sense of many tracklets on a relatively small area during the same time window, the more the merrier
- Individuals/tracklets have to be identifiable (ie. it must be possible to link all locations added by one individual to some kind of id) at least for some time periods
- Bonus for underlying ground truth (eg. a fair going on)

I have searched the webs for about 4 hours now but couldn't find anything that fits at least the first two requirements, any ideas are very welcome.